# how to make the brush smooth without lines in the middle

Tags: c#, wpf, blend

[image]

Hi all,
as you see in previous brush there is lines in the middle,
 it isn't so smooth
how to make it smooth? (how to remove that lines)
i create it with blend

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.452,1.962" StartPoint="1.164,-0.352">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF202020" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF545454" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Can you post your code that's creating the brush. Is this a gradient brush?

Comment: ok you can check the code now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The banding is an artefact of the gradient algorithm. It has to break the area in to bands each filled with a slightly different colour. The edges are in fact an optical illusion which has the effect of making them more visible than you would think. To reduce this effect you need to reduce the width of each band.

The solutions are:

1. Fill over a smaller area - each band is narrower.
2. Increase the number of bands. Make the contrast between the two extremes larger.
3. Increase the colour resolution of the display. If you have more colours to choose from then there will be a larger usable range between the two end colours.

I do realise that these solutions are either a) not possible or b) not practical. This is a problem you are going to have to live with.

One practical solution might be to replace the brush with an image created in Photoshop or other image processing package. This might give you an image with less banding - but then you are restricted to the size of the image - you can't grow it without pixelation.

Answer (score 7):

Some time ago I wrote smooth linear gradient for my WPF project. It removes the banding, but there are two caveats:

- It cannot be used for databound colors or `{DynamicResource}`.
- It currently supports only vertical gradient, as that was all I needed

It is implemented as dynamicly created `ImageBrush`, using [Ordered Dithering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_dithering). Additionaly, it is also a `MarkupExtension`, as one cannot simply inherit any `Brush` class (the're all sealed).

```
/// <summary>
/// Brush that lets you draw vertical linear gradient without banding.
/// </summary>
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(Brush))]
public class SmoothLinearGradientBrush : MarkupExtension
{
    private static PropertyInfo dpiX_;
    private static PropertyInfo dpiY_;
    private static byte[,] bayerMatrix_ = 
    {
        { 1, 9, 3, 11 },
        { 13, 5, 15, 7 },
        { 1, 9, 3, 11 },
        { 16, 8, 14, 6 }
    };

    static SmoothLinearGradientBrush()
    {
        dpiX_ = typeof(SystemParameters).GetProperty("DpiX", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
        dpiY_ = typeof(SystemParameters).GetProperty("Dpi", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gradient color at the top
    /// </summary>
    public Color From { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gradient color at the bottom
    /// </summary>
    public Color To { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        //If user changes dpi/virtual screen height during applicaiton lifetime,
        //wpf will scale the image up for us.
        int width = 20;
        int height = (int)SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight;
        int dpix = (int)dpiX_.GetValue(null);
        int dpiy = (int)dpiY_.GetValue(null);


        int stride = 4 * ((width * PixelFormats.Bgr24.BitsPerPixel + 31) / 32);

        //dithering parameters
        double bayerMatrixCoefficient = 1.0 / (bayerMatrix_.Length + 1);
        int bayerMatrixSize = bayerMatrix_.GetLength(0);

        //Create pixel data of image
        byte[] buffer = new byte[height * stride];

        for (int line = 0; line < height; line++)
        {
            double scale = (double)line / height;

            for (int x = 0; x < width * 3; x += 3)
            {
                //scaling of color
                double blue = ((To.B * scale) + (From.B * (1.0 - scale)));
                double green = ((To.G * scale) + (From.G * (1.0 - scale)));
                double red = ((To.R * scale) + (From.R * (1.0 - scale)));

                //ordered dithering of color
                //source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_dithering
                buffer[x + line * stride] = (byte)(blue + bayerMatrixCoefficient * bayerMatrix_[x % bayerMatrixSize, line % bayerMatrixSize]);
                buffer[x + line * stride + 1] = (byte)(green + bayerMatrixCoefficient * bayerMatrix_[x % bayerMatrixSize, line % bayerMatrixSize]);
                buffer[x + line * stride + 2] = (byte)(red + bayerMatrixCoefficient * bayerMatrix_[x % bayerMatrixSize, line % bayerMatrixSize]);
            }
        }

        var image = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, dpix, dpiy, PixelFormats.Bgr24, null, buffer, stride);
        image.Freeze();
        var brush = new ImageBrush(image);
        brush.Freeze();
        return brush;
    }
}
```

Usage in resource dictionary:

```
<local:SmoothLinearGradientBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" 
                                 From="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundColorLight}" 
                                 To="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundColorDark}" />
```

and then in control style:

```
<Style ...>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

A cheap and dirty option from another answer of mine is this:

Add the gradient to a container, give it a small negative margin so it spills over a little, add a BlurEffect to the gradient, and then turn on ClipToBounds on the parent container. This way the gradient evens out a bit nicer at the expense of performance.

Depending on your use case, this may not be viable, however.

Example:

```
<Grid Height="26" Margin="-5,0" ClipToBounds="True">
    <Grid Margin="-5">
        <Grid.Effect>
            <BlurEffect Radius="6" />
        </Grid.Effect>
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop x:Name="GradientStop7" Color="Magenta" Offset="0.0" />
                <GradientStop x:Name="GradientStop8" Color="DarkOrchid" Offset=".2" />
                <GradientStop x:Name="GradientStop9" Color="Purple" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The negative gradient should be equal to the blur radius so that it doesn't become transparent on the edges.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the solution from ghord, I implemented a more versatile gradient. I implemented it as a dynamic image in a FrameworkElement. You can specify the colors in all four corners, and it works especially well with very light colored gradients without any banding. The image is scaled in a way that it produces pixel-perfect dithering even with high DPI monitors.

```
/// <summary>
/// A class that draws a pixel-perfect, dithered gradient image
/// </summary>
public class DitheredGradientImage : FrameworkElement
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TopLeftColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(TopLeftColor), typeof(Color), typeof(DitheredGradientImage),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Colors.Transparent, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, OnColorsChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TopRightColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(TopRightColor), typeof(Color), typeof(DitheredGradientImage),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Colors.Transparent, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, OnColorsChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BottomLeftColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(BottomLeftColor), typeof(Color), typeof(DitheredGradientImage),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Colors.Transparent, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, OnColorsChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BottomRightColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(BottomRightColor), typeof(Color), typeof(DitheredGradientImage),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Colors.Transparent, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, OnColorsChanged));

    public Color TopLeftColor
    {
        get { return (Color)this.GetValue(TopLeftColorProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(TopLeftColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public Color TopRightColor
    {
        get { return (Color)this.GetValue(TopRightColorProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(TopRightColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public Color BottomLeftColor
    {
        get { return (Color)this.GetValue(BottomLeftColorProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(BottomLeftColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public Color BottomRightColor
    {
        get { return (Color)this.GetValue(BottomRightColorProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(BottomRightColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public Color TopColor
    {
        get { return (TopLeftColor == TopRightColor) ? TopLeftColor : default(Color); }
        set { TopLeftColor = value; TopRightColor = value; }
    }

    public Color BottomColor
    {
        get { return (BottomLeftColor == BottomRightColor) ? BottomLeftColor : default(Color); }
        set { BottomLeftColor = value; BottomRightColor = value; }
    }

    public Color LeftColor
    {
        get { return (TopLeftColor == BottomLeftColor) ? TopLeftColor : default(Color); }
        set { TopLeftColor = value; BottomLeftColor = value; }
    }

    public Color RightColor
    {
        get { return (TopRightColor == BottomRightColor) ? TopRightColor : default(Color); }
        set { TopRightColor = value; BottomRightColor = value; }
    }

    public double DpiScaleX => VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this).DpiScaleX;
    public double DpiScaleY => VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this).DpiScaleY;

    public double DpiX => VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this).PixelsPerInchX;
    public double DpiY => VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this).PixelsPerInchX;

    private WriteableBitmap bitmap = null;
    private int lastPixelWidth = 0;
    private int lastPixelHeight = 0;

    protected static void OnColorsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Force redraw by resetting width and height
        if (d is DitheredGradientImage di)
        {
            di.lastPixelWidth = 0;
            di.lastPixelHeight = 0;
        }
    }

    protected void Update(int pixelWidth, int pixelHeight)
    {
        // Check if bitmap needs recreation, because it it is either
        // not initialized, or too small to fit the current element size
        if ((bitmap == null) ||
            (bitmap.PixelWidth < pixelWidth) ||
            (bitmap.PixelHeight < pixelHeight))
        {
            // Oversize, so that continuous resizing doesn't lead to constant bitmap recreation
            bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(pixelWidth + 256, pixelHeight + 256, DpiX, DpiY, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null);

            // As the old bitmap is gone, reset values so it gets redrawn anyway
            lastPixelWidth = 0;
            lastPixelHeight = 0;
        }

        // The gradient needs to be drawn to the exact size required
        if ((lastPixelWidth != pixelWidth) || (lastPixelHeight != pixelHeight))
        {
            // Draw a line-based test pattern to verify proper pixel scaling (or the lack of)
            //DrawTestPattern(pixelWidth, pixelHeight);

            // Draw the actual gradient
            DrawGradient(pixelWidth, pixelHeight);

            // Store values to avoid redrawing when nothing has changed
            lastPixelWidth = pixelWidth;
            lastPixelHeight = pixelHeight;
        }
    }

    protected void DrawTestPattern(int pixelWidth, int pixelHeight)
    {
        try
        {
            // Reserve the back buffer for updates.
            bitmap.Lock();

            unsafe
            {
                // Get a pointer to the back buffer.
                IntPtr pBackBuffer = bitmap.BackBuffer;

                for (int y = 0; y < pixelHeight; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < pixelWidth; x++)
                    {
                        // Draw alternate black and white lines
                        uint colorData = (y % 2 == 0) ? 0xFF000000 : 0xFFFFFFFF;
                        *(uint*)(pBackBuffer + (y * bitmap.BackBufferStride) + (x * 4)) = colorData;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Specify the area of the bitmap that changed.
            bitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, pixelWidth, pixelHeight));
        }
        finally
        {
            // Release the back buffer and make it available for display.
            bitmap.Unlock();
        }
    }

    private const byte matrixSize = 4;

    private static readonly float[,] scaledMatrix = CalculateMatrix(matrixSize);

    private static float[,] CalculateMatrix(byte n)
    {
        uint[,] uintMatrix = new uint[n, n];
        uint divisor = uint.MaxValue;
        for (ushort i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (ushort j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                uintMatrix[i, j] = BitReverse(8, BitInterleave((ushort)(i ^ j), i));
                if ((uintMatrix[i, j] != 0) && (divisor > uintMatrix[i, j]))
                    divisor = uintMatrix[i, j];
            }
        }

        float[,] floatMatrix = new float[n, n];
        float coefficient = 1.0f / (uintMatrix.Length * divisor);
        for (ushort i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (ushort j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                floatMatrix[i, j] = uintMatrix[i, j] * coefficient;
            }
        }

        return floatMatrix;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reverse all bits
    /// </summary>
    private static uint BitReverse(byte bits, uint value)
    {
        uint left = (uint)1 << (bits - 1);
        uint right = 1;
        uint result = 0;

        for (int i = (bits - 1); i >= 1; i -= 2)
        {
            result |= (value & left) >> i;
            result |= (value & right) << i;
            left >>= 1;
            right <<= 1;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Bitwise interleave of two 16-bit unsigned integers
    /// </summary>
    private static uint BitInterleave(ushort x, ushort y)
    {
        uint _x = x;
        _x = (_x | (_x << 8)) & 0x00FF00FF;
        _x = (_x | (_x << 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F;
        _x = (_x | (_x << 2)) & 0x33333333;
        _x = (_x | (_x << 1)) & 0x55555555;

        uint _y = y;
        _y = (_y | (_y << 8)) & 0x00FF00FF;
        _y = (_y | (_y << 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F;
        _y = (_y | (_y << 2)) & 0x33333333;
        _y = (_y | (_y << 1)) & 0x55555555;

        return (uint)(_x | (_y << 1));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Draws the gradient
    /// </summary>
    protected void DrawGradient(int pixelWidth, int pixelHeight)
    {
        // Caching the color values is mandatory, JIT compiler doesn't seem to cache access
        byte topLeftR = TopLeftColor.R, topLeftG = TopLeftColor.G, topLeftB = TopLeftColor.B, topLeftA = TopLeftColor.A;
        byte topRightR = TopRightColor.R, topRightG = TopRightColor.G, topRightB = TopRightColor.B, topRightA = TopRightColor.A;
        byte bottomLeftR = BottomLeftColor.R, bottomLeftG = BottomLeftColor.G, bottomLeftB = BottomLeftColor.B, bottomLeftA = BottomLeftColor.A;
        byte bottomRightR = BottomRightColor.R, bottomRightG = BottomRightColor.G, bottomRightB = BottomRightColor.B, bottomRightA = BottomRightColor.A;

        try
        {
            // Reserve the back buffer for updates.
            bitmap.Lock();

            unsafe
            {
                // Get a pointer to the back buffer.
                IntPtr pBackBuffer = bitmap.BackBuffer;
                int backBufferStride = bitmap.BackBufferStride;

                for (int y = 0; y < pixelHeight; y++)
                {
                    float incYScale = y / (float)pixelHeight;
                    float decYScale = 1 - (y / (float)pixelHeight);

                    for (int x = 0; x < pixelWidth; x++)
                    {
                        float incXScale = x / (float)pixelWidth;
                        float decXScale = 1 - (x / (float)pixelWidth);

                        float r = (((topLeftR * decXScale) + (topRightR * incXScale)) * decYScale) +
                                    (((bottomLeftR * decXScale) + (bottomRightR * incXScale)) * incYScale);
                        float g = (((topLeftG * decXScale) + (topRightG * incXScale)) * decYScale) +
                                    (((bottomLeftG * decXScale) + (bottomRightG * incXScale)) * incYScale);
                        float b = (((topLeftB * decXScale) + (topRightB * incXScale)) * decYScale) +
                                    (((bottomLeftB * decXScale) + (bottomRightB * incXScale)) * incYScale);
                        float a = (((topLeftA * decXScale) + (topRightA * incXScale)) * decYScale) +
                                    (((bottomLeftA * decXScale) + (bottomRightA * incXScale)) * incYScale);

                        byte* p = (byte*)(pBackBuffer + (y * backBufferStride) + (x * 4));

                        p[0] = (byte)(b + scaledMatrix[x % matrixSize, y % matrixSize]);
                        p[1] = (byte)(g + scaledMatrix[x % matrixSize, y % matrixSize]);
                        p[2] = (byte)(r + scaledMatrix[x % matrixSize, y % matrixSize]);
                        p[3] = (byte)a;
                    }
                }

                // Specify the area of the bitmap that changed.
                bitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, pixelWidth, pixelHeight));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            bitmap.Unlock();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        // Math.Round seems to be used in WPF, so it's important to use the 
        // same function, otherwise you sometimes don't get pixel-perfect drawing
        int pixelWidth = (int)Math.Round(RenderSize.Width * DpiScaleX);
        int pixelHeight = (int)Math.Round(RenderSize.Height * DpiScaleY);

        // Exit if there is nothing to draw
        if ((pixelWidth == 0) || (pixelHeight == 0)) return;

        // Refresh the bitmap
        Update(pixelWidth, pixelHeight);

        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            // The bitmap will be oversized, and DrawingContext.DrawImage doesn't provide
            // any other way to specify a source image rect
            CroppedBitmap croppedBitmap = new CroppedBitmap(bitmap, new Int32Rect(0, 0, pixelWidth, pixelHeight));
            dc.DrawImage(croppedBitmap, new Rect(default(Point), RenderSize));
        }
    }
}
```

Using it in XAML:

```
<local:DitheredGradientImage TopLeftColor="#e5e5e5" TopRightColor="#ffffff" BottomLeftColor="#ffffff" BottomRightColor="#f5f5f5" />
```