# Silverlight - Brush banding

Tags: silverlight, brush

Can someone tell me how to increase the number of "color bands" on a Silverlight gradient brush?

The question is marked as answered below, but it really isn't a solution to use bitmaps instead of gradient brushes as my users can modify their background dynamically. This is most obvious when full screen gradients are used.

[how to make the brush smooth without lines in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801524/how-to-make-the-brush-smooth-without-lines-in-the-middle)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can only give you half an answer - the general principles on why this happens and how to avoid it. As to the implementation in SL, I can only give you some general ideas as I'm not an expert there.

Those bands result from the limited color depth of the display. To reduce the effect, the gradient has to be made slightly noisy. The simplest way to do is to calculate the color from the gradient as a floating number, and then round it to an integer in a weighted, random manner - like this:

```
correct_value = linear_gradient(x,y)     // e.g 25.3
whole_part = round_down(correct_value)   // 25
frac_part = correct_value - whole_part   // 0.3
color_used = whole_part
if (true_with_probability(frac_part)):
  color_used = color_used + 1            // color_used == 25 with 70% chance
                                         //               26 with 30% chance
```

Here is an example of using this technique (on the left is the effect of simply rounding to the nearest integer, right is rounding with noise):

[image: Smooth gradient] [image: Noisy gradient]

As to how to implement that in your case - I assume there would be some way to create a custom `Brush` object that would allow you to do the calculations per pixel, or alternatively some sort of shader functionality which could help. If those are not possible, you can also simply generate a bitmap using this logic, and use that bitmap as the brush (I believe this would be `ImageBrush`, but that's just from googling).

Perhaps somebody with more Silverlight knowledge can chime in and provide the best implementation in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. And  believe this is indeed a Silverlight specific issue as if I use a bitmap created in Photoshop for the background, it displays perfectly. Also, if I add extra gradient stops the problem reduces as there seems to be a fixed number of bands between gradient stops (seems to be about 70). I could add these in code but it's extra work that shouldn't have to be done. Is there a way to even double the number of bands between gradient stops as 70 is very obvious on large monitors.

Comment: Appologies, the number of bands seems to vary based on the actual color difference between the gradient stops...

Comment: Exactly - the smaller the difference, the wider the bands will be (fewer actual colors exist to use between the stops). Photoshop has a better algorithm for drawing the gradients than the default Silverlight one (most probably much better than the simple solution I described here).

Comment: Makes sense, thing is, the closer the colors in the gradients get, the more noticable the banding. So I suppose the answer is this is just the way SL works?