# Set bits per pixel in WPF-Desktop program

Tags: c#, wpf

I noticed ugly banding issues when using Gradients in WPF, and saw that a solution was to set the "bits per pixel" property to 32.
The thing is that the property seem to be Windows Phone only, ie not working on a program for desktop devices, since trying to add [this string](http://nediml.wordpress.com/2012/05/11/set-32-bits-per-pixel-for-your-wp-app/) in the ApplicationManifest didn't seem to do anything.

Does anyone know if/how I can set this property?

Thank you.

My function which draws the gradients:

```
public LinearGradientBrush getGradient(Color c1, Color c2, double opacity)
{
    LinearGradientBrush gradient = new LinearGradientBrush();
    gradient.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
    gradient.EndPoint = new Point(1, 1);
    gradient.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(c1, 0.0));
    gradient.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(c2, 1.0));
    gradient.Opacity = opacity;
    return gradient;
}
```

I draw the gradients off of the two most dominant colors in an AlbumCover. You can see the two colors on the top left of the window. I then call the getGradient-function with this:

```
getGradient(Colors[0], Colors[1], 0.5); // 0.5 is dynamic depending on the brightness of those colors. Tried with 1 opacity but it's still the same.
```

Here are the sample images (in PNG and uploaded without compression)

- [Image1](http://i.cubeupload.com/uP886o.png)
- [Image2](http://i.cubeupload.com/JUG0NK.png)
- [Image3](http://i.cubeupload.com/w7xFzQ.png)

As you can see, there is banding going on. There are worse examples but I can't remember what Cover gave it.

Please notice that Image1 does not have banding on it's AlbumCover. Even though there is a gradient on it.

Comment: @HighCore What? banding is not caused by a bad video-card, and if so, my two 770's should be enough to draw gradients, yes?

Comment: @HighCore I'm sorry but your comments aren't really helping me. My problems are real and I want to know how to amp the pixelformat for my WPF application. To get banding - try draw a gradient with really similar colors. You'll most likely get the same result as I get.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I would think that your color depth would come from your Windows display settings. Is that set to 24 or 32 bit?

Comment: could you please post some screens of what you see? also please share some sample code to draw the same.

Comment: @vesan I have the system default on Windows 8.1, which is 32-bit?? Gradients on with 32-bit looks smooth. So it's not my hardware.

Comment: @pushpraj Updated the original question with examples =)

Answer (score 2):

By doing a quick search I found some suggestions that the issue may be just a visual effect that is a result of having only 256 values for each of R, G and B channels that defines a color and the way that gradients work. If You try to cover a large area with a gradient, it'll divide it into smaller areas filled with solid colors, slightly changing between neighbouring areas. Additionally, there is an optical illusion called [Mach bands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_bands) that makes the borders of the areas even more visible.

Take a look at those links for more information and some suggested solutions:

- [how to make the brush smooth without lines in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801524/how-to-make-the-brush-smooth-without-lines-in-the-middle)
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cea96578-a6b3-4b29-b813-e3643d7770ae/lineargradientbrush-can-see-individual-gradient-steps?forum=wpf

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. But I think I've come up with a solution. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

After digging around a long time I finally found the best solution:

Adding a little bit of noise to the image! This does mean I have to draw the gradient myself, but I believe the quality will be much better.

I will update this post with the algorithm itself and examples when I'm done writing.

Stay tuned I guess.

Comment: In the first link I mentioned in my answer, You can find a suggestion to use ordered dithering and some sample code, which may be helpful (it's not in the accepted answer, but in the other one).